# Не отрабатывает первый рендер

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Есть страница с пиццами и панель с сортировками пицц[image: пиццы]

Центральная сортировка пока не нужна, только левая и правая. Сортировки работают отлично, но есть одно но. Вторая сортировка (популярность, цена...) работает только после того, как активируется первая сортировка. Помогите с решением данной проблемы. Код:

```
function App() {

const data = [
  {
    title: "Пепперонни",
    image: "/images/pizzaPeperoni.png",
    price: 120,
    modalContent: "20 грамм картошки",
    isMeat: 1,
    popularity: 36,
  },
  {
    title: "Салями",
    image: "/images/pizzaSalami.png",
    price: 99,
    modalContent: "40 грамм мандавошки",
    isMeat: 1,
    popularity: 24,
  },
  {
    title: "Гавайская",
    image: "/images/pizzaGavaiskia.png",
    price: 81,
    modalContent: "15 мандаринок",
    isMeat: 1,
    popularity: 18,
  },
  {
    title: "Грибная",
    image: "/images/pizzaGribnaia.png",
    price: 144,
    modalContent: "90 ведер воды",
    isMeat: 0,
    popularity: 22,
  },
  {
    title: "4 сезона",
    image: "/images/pizzaFourSesons.png",
    price: 120,
    modalContent: "150 домов",
    isMeat: 0,
    popularity: 12,
  },
  {
    title: "Терияки",
    image: "/images/pizzaTeriyaki.png",
    price: 72,
    modalContent: "3 царства",
    isMeat: 1,
    popularity: 25,
  }
  ]

const [isRender, setIsRender] = useState(data)
const [fillerValue, setFillerValue] = useState(2)
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

const filterByTitle = data.filter(item => {
  return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
})

let filterByFiller = (fillerValue) => {
  return fillerValue === 2 ? data : data.filter((item) => {
    return item.isMeat === fillerValue
  })
}

function sortByField(field) {
  return field === 'popularity' ? filterByFiller(fillerValue).sort((a, b) => a[field] < b[field] ? 1 : -1) :
      filterByFiller(fillerValue).sort((a, b) => a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1)
}

function cardsRender(state) {
  return state.map(({...item}, index) =>
        <Card
            key={index}
            {...item}
        />
    )
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <PizzaBackground />
    <Cart />
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Header
          setValue= {id => setValue(id)}
          filterByTitle={filterByTitle}
          setIsRender={setIsRender}
      />
      <div className="sorting">
        <ol id="left">
          <li padding-right="300px" onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(filterByFiller(1))
            setFillerValue(1)
            }}>Мясные</li>
          <li padding-right="400px" onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(filterByFiller(0))
            setFillerValue(0)
            }}>Вегетарианские</li>
          <li padding-right="200px" onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(filterByFiller(2))
            setFillerValue(2)
          }}>Все</li>
        </ol>
        <ol id="center">
          <li>От <input maxLength={11} name="number" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} /> руб.</li>
          <li>До <input maxLength={11} name="number" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} /> руб.</li>
        </ol>
        <ol id="right">
          <p>Сортировать по:</p>
          <li><button onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(sortByField('popularity'))
            console.log(isRender)
          }}>Популярности</button></li>
          <li><button onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(sortByField('price'))
            console.log(isRender)
          }}>Цене (по возрастанию)</button></li>
          <li><button onClick={() => {
            setIsRender(sortByField('title'))
            console.log(isRender)
          }}>Алфавиту</button></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div className="menu">
        {cardsRender(isRender)}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

В консоли при клике на правую сортировку правильно выдаёт всё, проблема только в отрисовке на странице

Comment: Эм... Так проблема в чем? Сортировка не работает или первичный рендер?

Comment: Про рендер наверное зря сказал, проблема в том, что вторая сортировка работает только после первой. Первый рендер я имел ввиду, чтобы вторая сортировка сразу же работала

Comment: А проблема то в чем? Вот жмете на среднюю сортировку - и?

Comment: Не, про среднюю сортировку забудьте. У меня работает вторая сортировка (которая популярность\цена\алфавит) только после первой сортировки (мясные\веган\все), то есть пока не нажму на какую-нибудь кнопку из первой сортировки - вторая работать не будет. Я думал это функция сортировки не рабочая, а в логах всё норм - вторая сортировка выводит отсортированный массив, но вот почему-то на странице сортируется вторая только после первой

Comment: Так у вас же условие стоит `return fillerValue === 2 ? data : ` Получается, когда значение `fillerValue === 2` сортировка выполняться будет, только вот объект не меняется, а 2 у вас по умолчанию. Попробуйте вот так выполнять сохранение setIsRender({ ...sortByField('title') })

Comment: консольная ошибка "state.map is not a function"

Comment: А, у вас же массив. Тогда так setIsRender([ ...sortByField('title') ]) или setIsRender(() => { const res =  sortByField('title'); return [ ...res ] }) одним словом, можно попробовать оператором spread сделать копию массива, что бы react понял, что состояние изменилось

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает на ура, но я правда не понял, почему нужна здесь копия массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **React** - это библиотека/фреймворк **javaScript**.

В javaScript объекты при копировании передают ссылки на себя, а не сами данные.
 Массив это тоже объект.

Т.е. один объект существует в javaScript в одном экземпляре, все переменные ссылаются на него.

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const arrCopy = arr;
arrCopy.push(2);
console.log(arr === arrCopy);
console.log(arr, arrCopy);
```

Как видно из примера, 2 переменных равны друг другу, хотя визуально мы изменили вторую переменную.
Скажите: *Так ведь данные одни и те же! Поэтому равно.* **Проверим**

```js
const arrOne = [1,2];
const arrTwo = [1,2];
console.log(arrOne === arrTwo);
```

Данные одинаковы, но массивы разные, т.к. создано 2 разных объекта.

У массивов есть методы, которые возвращают новый массив, например **filter()** или **map()**.

Метод **sort** не возвращает новый объект, а возвращает ссылку на исходный объект, но отсортированный.

Самый простой способ создать новый объект, это оператор **spread( ... )**.
**Spread** не делает полный клон объекта, а только копирует первый уровень, однако для React этого вполне достаточно, что бы понять, что данные изменились и надо обновить состояние компонента.

```js
const mas = [1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 0, 2];
const mas1 = mas.sort();
const mas2 = mas.filter(item => item < 6);
console.log(mas === mas1);
console.log(mas === mas2);
console.log(mas === [ ...mas1]);
console.log(mas, [ ...mas1 ]);
```

Теперь посмотрим на вашу функцию, обладая знаниями выше

```
let filterByFiller = (fillerValue) => {
    return fillerValue === 2 ? data : data.filter((item) => {
        return item.isMeat === fillerValue
    })
}
```

При значении `fillerValue === 2` функция вернет **data**, где **data** это ссылка на объект.
`const [isRender, setIsRender] = useState(data)` - здесь **isRender** имеет ту же ссылку, т.е. ссылаются они на один и тот же объект.

При изменении состояния компонента `setIsRender(sortByField('price'))` передаем ту же ссылку на объект, который был до этого. React думает, что данные не изменились и рендер не нужен.
Для того, что бы React понял, что данные изменились, необходимо передать новый объект.

Таким образом, выполняя изменения состояния, с использованием spread оператора `setIsRender([ ...sortByField('price') ])` приводит к обновлению **react** компонента.

Почему это работает при первоначальном клике на другие сортировки? Потому что вы возвращали результат метода **filter()**, который возвращает **новый объект**.

Comment: Спасибо огромное