# Не обновляется состояние

Tags: reactjs

Есть 3 кнопки в окне, по нажатию на которые происходит сортировка продуктов:

```js
const sortHandler = (name: any, idx: number): void => {
    switch (name) {
            case EProductSort.popular: // популярности
                setProducts(products);
                break;
            case EProductSort.price: // цене
                const sortProductsByPrice = products.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    return a.price - b.price;
                });
                setProducts(sortProductsByPrice);
                break;
            case EProductSort.alphabet: // алфавиту
                const sortProductsByAlphabet = products.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                setProducts(sortProductsByAlphabet);
                break;
            default:
                setProducts(list);
                break;
        }
    };
```

`setProducts` и `products` передаются в `props`:

```js
<Filter setProducts={setProducts} products={products} />
```

```js
const { list } = useSelector((state: IState) => state.products);
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<Array<IProduct>>(list);
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопки, то попадаю в определенный `case`, там проверяю массивы, которые корректно отсортированы, но состояние продуктов не обновляется

Comment: [Почему не обновляется состояние при изменении массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467523/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80/1468251#1468251) - Подробно и описывал, почему так происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `sort()` не создает новый объект `Array`, а производит сортировку переданного массива.

Как вариант - просто сделать "другой" массив из "старого", но отсортированного.

```js
const sortHandler = (name: any, idx: number): void => {
    switch (name) {
            case EProductSort.popular: // популярности
                setProducts([...products]);
                break;
            case EProductSort.price: // цене
                const sortProductsByPrice = products.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    return a.price - b.price;
                });
                setProducts([...sortProductsByPrice]);
                break;
            case EProductSort.alphabet: // алфавиту
                const sortProductsByAlphabet = products.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                setProducts([...sortProductsByAlphabet]);
                break;
            default:
                setProducts([...list]);
                break;
        }
    };
```