# Общий стейт на все компоненты в мапе

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: стейт пробрасываю в нужный компонент мапом, и ожидаю что для каждого рендера итерации будет разный стейт.
Пример:
В App.js храню стейт, его пробрасываю в Cart.jsx, а после:

```
{props.cartContent.map((cartItem, index) =>
    <CartItem
        key={index}
        amount={props.amount}
        setAmount={props.setAmount}
        {...cartItem}
     />
 )}
```

в cartItem. В нём следующая тема:

```
<button onClick={() => setAmount(prev => prev > 1 ? prev - 1 : amount)}> - </button>
<h3>{amount}</h3>
<button onClick={() => setAmount(prev => prev + 1)}>+</button>
```

На странице получается отрендеренные 5 карточек, и при изменении счётчика у одной карточки, такое же значение применяется и на все другие. Если стейт оставить в CartItem всё ок, но мне он нужен в аппе

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [Как создать список счетчиков с собственным состоянием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474996/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/1475029#1475029)

Comment: Вообще вроде да, но в конце вы написали, что можно перенести стейты в родительский и пробрасывать данные. В этом у меня и проблема. Мне нужно чтобы стейт был именно в родительском. Вообще я понимаю что делаю бред, мол стейт объявил а итерирую совсем другое.. Вообще, я думаю как-то можно обойтись одним стейтом и на каждый новый компонент новое 
независимое значение стейта

Comment: Я не очень понял, вам надо чтобы все кнопки меняли одно состояние или чтобы каждая кнопка меняла своё значение?

Comment: каждая кнопка меняла своё значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Организуем стейт в компоненте родителе:

```
const datas = [
  {value: 0},
  {value: 0},
  {value: 0},
  {value: 0},
];

const Card = ({ cardValue, change, idx }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{cardValue}</span>
      <button onClick={() => change(idx, 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => change(idx, -1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(datas);

  const change = (idx, val) => {
    const elements = [ ...cards ];
    elements[idx].value += val;
    setCards(elements);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cards.map((item, index) => <Card key={index} cardValue={item.value} change={change} idx={index} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/schetchik-e5kes0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: а если длина datas динамическая?

Comment: @Spenkau А какая разница? )

Comment: Всё, допёр, спасибо большое. Я на протяжении года задаю вопросы и именно вы мне всегда отвечаете, вы лучший)

Comment: Сделал, но у меня остался вопрос. В функции change вы создаётё копию массива cards, почему сразу к cards обращаться, а не к копии?

Comment: @Spenkau посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467523/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80/1468251#1468251) - думаю станет понятно, зачем нужна копия массива ) ну и поэкпериментируйте, попробуйте убрать копию и понаблюдать за поведентем