# Как изменить цвет элемента по клику в другом компоненте?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

Есть блок "place_1", по умолчанию зеленого цвета. При клике на этот элемент появляется модальное окно, где есть кнопка "Бронь". По клику "Бронь" блок "place_1" должен из зеленого окрашиваться в красный. Поменять цвет не получается так как блок в другом компоненте.

```
import Modal from "../modal/modal";
import { useState } from "react";


function Freelance () {
    const [modalActive, setModalActive ] = useState(false)

    return(

        <div className="freelance_conteiner">
                <div className="freelance_office">
                        <div className="place_1" onClick={()=>setModalActive(true)}>1</div>
                        <Modal active={modalActive} setActive={setModalActive}/>
                </div>
        </div>
     
    )
}

export default Freelance;
```

Модальное окно

```
import React from "react"
import "./modal.css"

const Modal = ({active, setActive}) =>{

    return(

    <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>

       <div className={active ? "modal__content active" : "modal"} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>

            <button className="modal_btn">Бронь!</button>

       </div>

    </div>

    )
}

export default Modal;
```

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Это проект по брони мест. При бронировании должно перекрашиваться в другой цвет. Сложности в том что это два разных компонента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте состояние в компоненте Freelance, которое будет отвечать за цвет и передайте функцию изменения цвета в компонент Modal в виде пропсов, как вы это делаете с setModalActive:

```
function Freelance () {
  const [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
  const [colorPlace, setColorPlace] = useState(false);

  return(

    <div className="freelance_conteiner">
      <div className="freelance_office">
        <div 
          className="place_1" 
          onClick={()=>setModalActive(true)}
          style={{color: colorPlace ? 'red' : 'green'}}
        >1</div>
        <Modal 
          active={modalActive} 
          setActive={setModalActive} 
          changeColor={setColorPlace}
        />
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Добавьте стиль цвета в зависимости от состояния переменной `style={{color: colorPlace ? 'red' : 'green'}}` 
В компоненте Modal при нажатии кнопки, вызывайте функцию и передавайте нужное значение:

```
const Modal = ({active, setActive, changeColor}) =>{
  return(
    <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>
      <div 
        className={active ? "modal__content active" : "modal"} 
        onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        <button 
          className="modal_btn" 
          onClick={() => changeColor(true)}
        >Бронь!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Для примера используется значение состояния как true/false

Так же можно не добавлять style а добавлять например новый класс, тогда строку

```
className="place_1"
```

Надо изменить на

```
className={'place_1 ' + colorPlace ? 'redClass' : 'greenClass'}
```

Comment: Для смены цвета туда сюда по нажатию на кнопку, можно делать так: `changeColor(c => !c)`

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает! А если мест будет больше то как перекрашивать только то место куда нажато бронь?

Comment: @NeroFighter либо декомпощировать даныые, либо создать массив "мест" и передавать индекс. Одним словом как то придумать, что передано и что нажато. Попробуйте, не получится, приходите с примером, как и что вам надо сделать и что не получилось

Comment: @NeroFighter Возможно этот ответ поможет вам в решении вашей задачи: [Каждый элемент управляет своими данными из состояния родителя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489288/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b5/1489301#1489301)