# React изменение состояния для каждого элемента по своему

Tags: reactjs

Делал приложение по бронированию мест, свободные места отмечены зеленым, занятые красным. "Места" у меня в массиве "placeDB" с помощью map вывожу. При клике на этот элемент появляется модальное окно, где есть кнопка "Бронь". По клику "Бронь" окрашиваются все блоки, а надо что бы каждый блок окрашивался только по своему по клику.

Фрагмент

```
import {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "../modal/modal";
import placeDB from "../placeDB/place";


function OfficeMap(){

const [modalActive, setModalActive ] = useState(false);
const [colorPlace, setColorPlace] = useState(false);

return(

<> 
<div className="freelance_office">  
    {placeDB.map((pop)=>{
        return(
            <div style={{background: colorPlace ? 'red' : 'green'}}  className={pop.className} onClick={()=>setModalActive(true)}>
                <p>Описание {pop.description}</p>
            </div>
        )
    })}
        
<Modal changeColor={setColorPlace} active={modalActive} setActive={setModalActive}/>
</div>
</>
)
}
export default OfficeMap;
```

в placeDB содержится

```
const placeDB = [
{id: 1,
description: "Место 1",
className: "open_description_place_1"
},

{
id: 2,
description: "Место 2",
className: "open_description_place_2"
},

{
id: 3,
description: "Место 3",
className: "open_description_place_3"
},

{
id: 4,
description: "Место 4",
className: "open_description_place_4"
},

{ id: 5,
description: "Место 5",
className: "open_description_place_5"
},

]

export default placeDB;
```

модальное окно

```
import React from "react"
import "./modal.css"

const Modal = ({active, setActive, changeColor}) =>{

return(

<div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>

   <div className={active ? "modal__content active" : "modal"} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>

        <button className="modal_btn" onClick={() => changeColor(c => !c)}>Бронь!</button>

   </div>

</div>

)

}


export default Modal;
```

Comment: Что это вы решили [пользователей плодить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490848/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5) ?

Comment: Нет на том аккаунте пишет You cant post new questions right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы добавли в структуру данных свойство, отвечающее за бронь места `isBronned: false`

Далее при нажатии на элемент сохраняем элемент в состоянии и передаем его в компонент Modal вместе с фукнцией по применению бронирования `bronned`.

При нажатии на кнопку бронь, передается id места и его статус (забронировано/не забронировано). Сохраняем эти значения.

Во время рендера списка смотрим на isBronned и в зависимости от этого закрашиваем нужным цветом.

```
const placeDB = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "Место 1",
    className: "open_description_place_1",
    isBronned: false
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    description: "Место 2",
    className: "open_description_place_2",
    isBronned: false
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    description: "Место 3",
    className: "open_description_place_3",
    isBronned: false
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    description: "Место 4",
    className: "open_description_place_4",
    isBronned: false
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    description: "Место 5",
    className: "open_description_place_5",
    isBronned: false
  }
];

const Modal = ({ active, setActive, changeColor, place }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"}
      onClick={() => setActive(false)}
    >
      <div
        className={active ? "modal__content active" : "modal"}
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        {place && (
          <button
            className="modal_btn"
            onClick={() => {
              changeColor(place.id, !place.isBronned);
            }}
          >
            {place?.isBronned
              ? `Снять бронь ${place?.description}`
              : `Забронировать ${place?.description}`}
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function OfficeMap() {
  const [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState(placeDB);
  const [selPlace, setSelPlace] = useState(null);

  const bronned = (id, bron) => {
    setPlaces(
      places.map((it) => {
        if (it.id === id) it.isBronned = bron;
        return it;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="freelance_office">
        {places.map((pop) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{ background: pop.isBronned ? "red" : "green" }}
              className={pop.className}
              onClick={() => {
                setModalActive(true);
                setSelPlace(pop);
              }}
            >
              <p>Описание {pop.description}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <Modal
          changeColor={bronned}
          place={selPlace}
          active={modalActive}
          setActive={setModalActive}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/dunamic-inputs-tuv45f?file=/src/App.js) - в самом низу раздел бронирования мест