# При клике менять класс и текст (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

```
const FoodList = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "weight": "0,5",
      "subscrible": "Печень утки или гуся",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "weight": "2",
      "subscrible": "Свежайшая сёмгушка",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "weight": "1",
      "subscrible": "Влажные корма с курицей",
      "available": false
    }
  ]

  let description = <div>текст 1 </div>;
  let unavailableText = <div className={s.unavailableText}>текст 2</div>

  const [text, setText] = useState(description);
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");

 const handleClick = () => {
    if (food.available === false) { 
      setActive(isActive);
      setText(unavailableText); 
      console.log("это ложь ") 
    } else 
    if (food.available === true) { 
      setActive(!isActive);
      setText(food.subscrible); 
      console.log("это истина ") }
  };

     <div className={s.wrapper} onClick={handleClick} >
        <div className={
            ((isActive && food.available === true) ? s.border : s.itemActive) ||  
            ((!isActive && food.available === true) ? s.border : s.itemDisable)
          }> ... 
        </div>
        <div className={s.subscrible} >
           {text} 
        </div>
     </div>
```

**Дано:** массив с элементами, у каждого есть ключ available (что означает В наличии или нет) булевого типа.

**Условие:**

- Если по элементу кликнули и он в наличии, то смени класс s.border на класс s.itemActive + смени текст description на setText(food.subscrible). При повторном клике верни обратно класс и текст.
- Если по элементу кликнули и он не в наличии, то смени класс s.border на класс s.itemDisable + смени текст description на unavailableText. При повторном клике верни обратно класс и текст.

**Проблемы:**

1. не меняется обратно текст при повторном клике.
2. для товаров не в наличии не меняется класс.

Comment: Одна из ошибок: Вы не меняете значение food.available по клику, хотя проверяете.

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491364/react-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83/1491389#1491389) - Очень похоже на то, какого поведения вы хотите достичь