# При открытии боковой панели предыдущая не закрывается React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В проекте на экран выводятся таблицы, на каждой таблице есть кнопка, открывающая боковую панель с инфо о таблице и разным функционалом. Если я кликаю на все таблицы, то эти боковые панели открываются каждая новая поверх предыдущей. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при открытии новой панели старая автоматически закрывалась.

Не могу понять, в каком компоненте даже прописать функцию, чтобы открытие одной панели закрывало другую...

Компонент таблицы с кнопкой открытия:

```
export const Table = ({
    table: table
}) => {
const [isOpenSideBar, setIsOpenSideBar] = useState(false);

function openSideBarNavigation() {
        updateXarrow();
        setIsOpenSideBar(true);
        updateXarrow();
    }

    function closeSideBarNavigation() {
        setIsOpenSideBar(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
{isOpenSideBar && (
                <>
                    <SideBarNavigation
                        table={table}
                        onClose={closeSideBarNavigation}
                        onTableCopyHandler={onCopyTable}
                        onTableDeleteHandler={onDeleteTable}
                        onChangeColumnVisibilityHandler={
                            onChangeColumnVisibilityHandler
                        }
                    />
                </>
            )}
<div
                    className={styles.MainContainer}
                    id={table.name}
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        border: "2px solid",
                        borderRadius: "3px",
                        margin: "10px",
                        backgroundColor: color
                    }}
                >
                    <div id="sideBar" className={styles.SideBar}></div>
                    <div className={styles.TableHead}>
                        <div
                            className={styles.HeaderContainer}
                        >
                        <button type="button" 
                        style={{ backgroundColor: color, border: "none", color: "aliceblue", cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onDoubleClick={openSideBarNavigation}
                        disabled={false}
                        >
                            {table.name}
                        </button>
                        </div>

                        <div
                            className={styles.InfoButton}
                            onClick={openModalWithTableInfo}
                        >
                            <InfoIcon />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ borderBottom: "solid 1px" }}>
                        {table.columns
                            ?.filter((el) => el.isVisible)
                            .map((column) => {
                                let components = [];
                                components.push(
                                    <Column column={column} key={column.name} />
                                );
                                return components;
                            })}
                    </div>
                </div>
</>
    );
};
```

И компонент боковой панели:

```
export const SideBarNavigation = ({
    onClose: onClose,
    table: selectedTable
}) => {
function getTableColumns() {
        let components = [];
        selectedTable.columns?.map((column, index) => {
            components.push(
                <div className={styles.NameContainer}>
                    <Column column={column} key={column.name} />
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={column.name}
                        checked={column.isVisible}
                        key={"column" + column.name}
                        onClick={() => handleChangeColumnVisible(index)}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        });
        return components;
    }
return createPortal(
        <>
            <div className={styles.SidePanel}>
                <label
                    className={styles.CloseButton}
                    htmlFor="side-checkbox"
                    onClick={onClose}
                >
                    +
                </label>
                <div className={styles.HeaderContainer}>
                    Действия с таблицей: {selectedTable.name}
                </div>
<div className={styles.ColumnContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.FieldsHeaderContainer}>
                        <label htmlFor="side-checkbox">Поля таблицы:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.FieldsContainer}>
                        {getTableColumns()}
                    </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </>,
        document.getElementById("react-modals")
    );
};
```

Comment: Вам надо вынести ваш SideBarNavigation за пределы компонента Table. Сейчас SideBarNavigation созадется для каждого Table и о существовании других не знает. Еще варинт передавать в родителя статус открытия панели(какой то ID) и при изменении ID проверять, если ID совпало, оставить открытым, нет, закрыть.

Comment: @SwaD Вы имеете в виду ID таблицы? или передавать ID боковой панели? Первый вариант пока не очень понимаю, как применить. То есть как его за пределы Table  передать

Comment: [Организовать рендер дочерних элементов с состоянием в основном, с передачей данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489288/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b5/1489301#1489301) - должно помочь

Comment: @SwaD а если я эти функции (открытие и закрытие) и стейт передала в родителя table? Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Ну например да. В родителя вынести компонент, а в Table, когда нажимают на "открыть" в родителя бы улетал некий идентификатор, что хотят открыть данные такой то таблицы, и родитель по этому id будет понимать, какие данные отрендерить в SideBarNavigation. Если компонент не выносить, а просто вынести в родителя "кто сейчас открыт"(назовем для примера openSideBar), то внутри Table для показа или скрытия сделайте проверку вмесо `{isOpenSideBar && (` что вроде такого `{table.id === openSideBar&& (` где **openSideBar** это пропс из родителя с идентификатором таблицы

Comment: @SwaD функционала в sideBar много, не получается его вынести на один уровень с Table. А каким образом из Table можно передать в родителя "кто сейчас открыт"?

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке выше, там пример, как это делается. В примере передается индекс текущего элемента в родителя и меняется значение. Вы можете передавать любое значение, которое вас устроит и будет правильным для вас. Там, в примере, `const datas`, считайте это это ваш массив `tables`

Comment: @SwaD const onClickOpenSideBar = (event) => {
        openSideBarNavigation(event.target.value);   
    }   так я из компонента table передаю в родителя имя таблицы, sideBar остался в table
function openSideBarNavigation(value) {
        console.log(value);
        setIsOpenSideBar(true);
    }    так я получила valuе, то есть имя таблицы, в родителе table. Но ума не приложу, как прописать условие, чтобы открыть только одно окно, кроме того сейчас по клику открывается боковая панель не к той таблице, на которую кликнули, а к самой последней в диаграмме

Comment: У вас в компонент Table прихоит только table(тут есть "признак" открытого сайдбара?), а условие по отображению в каждом компоненте Table свое

Comment: @SwaD было непросто разобраться, но помогло, заработало) Спасибо!)

Comment: От меня +1 за прокачку и стремление к развитию )